# autotabulate, failing with IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have an autotab function,

```
 <input type="text" class="autoTab" maxlength="2" /> :
 <input type="text" />

 autoTab : function(){
  $('.autoTab').on('keypress', function(e){

  if($(this).val().length + 1 === parseInt($(this).attr("maxlength"))){
     $(this).next().focus();
  }
});
```

}

it works fine in Chrome, but in IE, tabulate before write de last character, and it is not written.

I tried this:

```
    autoTab : function(){
     $('.autoTab').on('keypress', function(e){

       var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
       var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
       var isIE = (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)); 

    if((!isIE && $(this).val().length + 1 === parseInt($(this).attr("maxlength"))) || (isIE && $(this).val().length === parseInt($(this).attr("maxlength")))) {
       $(this).next().focus();
    } 
  });
}
```

it still works in Chrome, but in IE, I write 2 characters, and the cursor continues in the box.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the problem is that $(this).val().length + 1 evaluates to `true`, and you are hard-comparing it with int... for Internet Explorer that if is always true... as any number > 0 is true. Kind of weird behaviour. Would consider it as a bug.

Still easy way to fix it:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="autoTab" maxlength="2" /> :
<input type="text" />
```

JS:

```
$('.autoTab').on('keyup', function(e){
 if($(this).val().length == parseInt($(this).attr("maxlength"))){
     $(this).next().focus();
  }
});
```

This works fine on Chrome, Opera and IE.

[Live example](https://jsfiddle.net/57v84kux/2/)

Please note that I changed `===` to `==` in `if` statement and switched event to `onkeyup`.